# Discord Bot how to remove specific user roles

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I have been trying to make a bot which is, if the user has 'role 1' then he typed in channel 'role 2' the bot should check if he has any of 'role 1 or role 3' remove them from the user then add 'role 2' to the user.

```js
if (message == 'role 2') {
  var role = message.guild.roles.find("name", "2");

  if (message.member.roles.has('1')) {
    console.log('user has role 1');
    await message.member.removeRole("1");
    try {
      console.log('removed role 1');
    } catch(e){
      console.error(e)
    }
  }
  message.member.addRole(role);
}
```

But this isn't working, it's only adding roles not removing. `console.log` prints the following:

> DeprecationWarning: Collection#find: pass a function insteadDeprecationWarning: Collection#find: pass a function instead

How I can check for user roles and remove them before adding a new one?

---

Edit: error fixed with this new code:

```js
var role = message.guild.roles.find(role => role.name === "2")
```

But removing role command still not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- It appears like `message` is a [Message](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message) object. You should be comparing its [`content`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=content) property rather than the object itself.
- As [Saksham Saraswat](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10825872/saksham-saraswat) has also stated, you should pass a function into [`Collection.find()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Collection). Not doing so is deprecated.*
- [`Map.has()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/has) searches by key. [Collection](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Collection)s use Discord IDs as their keys, which are [Snowflakes](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/typedef/Snowflake). The ID shown in your code is not an ID, so **the block for that `if` statement isn't executed.**
- The way you've written `await(...)` is for executing a function. See the documentation [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await) on the `await` keyword. Note that it can only be used inside of [async functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function).
- You aren't catching any rejected [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise).*

<sup>* This is not affecting the current outcome of your code.</sup>

Implementing these solutions...

```js
if (message.content === 'role 2') {
  try {
    // message.member will be null for a DM, so check that the message is not a DM.
    if (!message.guild) return await message.channel.send('You must be in a guild.');

    // Find Role 2.
    const role2 = message.guild.roles.find(role => role.name === '2');
    if (!role2) return console.log('Role 2 missing.');

    // If the user has Role 1, remove it from them.
    const role1 = message.member.roles.find(role => role.name === '1');
    if (role1) await message.member.removeRole(role1);

    // Add Role 2 to the user.
    await message.member.addRole(role2);
  } catch(err) {
    // Log any errors.
    console.error(err);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, but i got error ";SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function", Could you help me to fix this please?

Comment: Define the most relevant function as async. If it's the message event, the callback should look like `async message => {...}` or `async function(message) {...}`.

Comment: you mean this one "bot.on('message', message => {" ?

Comment: Thank you so much it worked, i appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing in message.guild.roles.find you have to pass in a function like message.guild.roles.find(function); also I think find is deprecated which means, out of date and substituted for a better solution/function.

Comment: [`Collection.find()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Collection) is not deprecated as a whole; the deprecated part is the old `Collection.find('property', 'value')` usage. However, this is only a warning and should not be affecting the outcome of the rest of the code.

Comment: Thank you, Already fixed the error, but still remove function isn't working. when i type 'role 1' then 'role 2' it gives me multiple roles, i want the bot to remove other specific roles, Any idea?